# Permissions in DRF + Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I working on a project that has these models `Instructor`, `Student`, `Review`, `Class`.
only a `Student` that has a `Class` with `Instructor` can send a `Review`.
In the backend, I have a custom permission `IsStrudentOfInstructor` to determine a user can send a `Review` to an `Instructor` or not! and it works fine!

Question: How the frontend developer can determine to show the review form to the requested user or not?

Do I need to do any more work for that as a backend developer?

The frontend framework is Vue and the backend framework is Django Rest

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding all the user's permissions to the user profile endpoint. That way, frontend developer can store those permissions in the application state and enable/disable features based on that.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: 

GET /user/1/
{
    "username": ...,
    ...,
    "can_review": True
}
?